# Is it possible to set a user's group email notification settings via API?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

When a user joins a group, they are presented with options for linking their profile as well as choosing their email notification style on a screen like this:

[image: group membership settings]

Is it possible to set these values, in particular the email notification choices, via API?

I've found the API to add a member to a group (https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/admin/directory_v1/directory.members.insert), but not to set these meta-values pertaining to that membership.

Comment: Did you get the solution for the same?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, there is no way to set a user's mail delivery preferences via the current APIs.

Answer (score 0):

So while you can't get the mail preferences for each individual user, you can get some settings associated with the group. By using the Groups Settings API as per https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-settings/manage, you should be able to return a number of parameters which list the settings of said group.

Hope this helps,