# Is it possible to set a user's group email notification settings via API using google admin sdk?

Tags: php, google-admin-sdk, google-admin-settings-api

I know there is already a question asked before like this. but they doesn't have solution.

I've found the API to add a member to a group (https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/admin/directory_v1/directory.members.insert), but not to set these meta-values pertaining to that membership.

Can we get option to set email settings. like i want weekly or daily etc.

Here is link to old question :-
[Is it possible to set a user's group email notification settings via API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24963213/is-it-possible-to-set-a-users-group-email-notification-settings-via-api)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Administer domain resources, create reports, and manage subscriptions](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/), it is possible to manage internal and external group access, edit group notifications, configure discussion archiving and message moderation, and customize your account's user groups via [Manage group settings](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-settings/get_started).

However, please note that with regards to updating group notifications, resource representations given in [Groups](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-settings/v1/reference/groups#resource) that are currently available are for rejection notifications which are:

- `entry/apps:sendMessageDenyNotification`
- `entry/apps:sendMessageDenyNotification/text()`
- `entry/apps:defaultMessageDenyNotificationText`
- `entry/apps:defaultMessageDenyNotificationText/text()`